# UNIX sort with exponential values?

Tags: unix, sorting, csv, exponent

I have a csv file with 7 fields of data. I want to sort the 7th field in reverse numerial order (smallest values first). The 7th field of data looks like this:

```
0.498469643137
1
6.98112003175e-10
9.11278069581e-06
```

I have tried to use the UNIX sort tool like this:

```
$ sort -t"," -n -k -r 7 <my_file>
```

The problem I am having is that sort does not recognize exponential form. For example, sort thinks `6.98112003175e-10` is larger than `1`. How can I use sort to sort a csv column, but recognize the scientific notation? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

sort with '-g' option should do the trick for you.
-g option indicates 'use generic numerical value' for sorting

Comment: Thanks, I read the man page, but I didn't see anything about the -g flag. This did precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Please note, that your locale may assume another delimiter:
For example, in russian localization '`,`' character delimits parts of number rather than '`.`'. In this case you should take into account the LANG variable.

In my case LANG was set to `ru_RU.KOI8-R` and so `sort -g` gave me wrong result.

Comment: I had this problem as well. Here I found a solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/724338/how-to-set-lc-numeric-to-english-permanently

Answer (score 3):

So - just to give an example for those who do not know how to use it: instead of "-n" you use "-g".
`l = 1,0.3,6.01e-10`

`sort -t$',' -n example.txt`

`0.3
1
6.01e-10`

`sort -t$',' -g example.txt`

`6.01e-10
0.3
1`

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: how so? -g is for 'use generic numerical value'. Please read the above post about why to use -g. If you still have questions I will definitely try to answer them!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `-g`
2. Don't use `-n`

The correct command is `sort -g -k7,7 input.txt`